# Google-OAuth REST Api to react

Tags: reactjs, jwt, google-oauth

I have successfully created an API that uses passport-google-oauth to return a JWT. Currently when I go through the process using my API routes it returns a json object with a JWT Bearer token.

I am attempting to use Reactjs on the front end however am running into a couple issues.

In my signin button component I am just trying to retrieve the result with the bearer token to pass it into a reducer

1. When using Axios -> I am running into a CORS issue when using exios and cant return a result, when adding CORS into my build and a proxy to my react project I recieve the following error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
2. When I use a anchor tag with href link the authentication successfully works however it redirects to the /api/auth/google/callback link itself instead of allowing me to catch the bearer token and then run it through my reducers to save it into local storage and update my state.

Am I missing a step? Ive looked for a few hours at various resources online and cant seem to find the solution im looking for

**React**

(for simplicity at the moment I am just trying to catch the response, which should be returned bearer token, however I am unable to do this)

```
googleAuth = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    axios.get('/api/auth/google')
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.googleAuth}>Signin With Google</button>
    )
}
```

**API**

**Routes**

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    session: false,
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
}))

router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { session: false }), generateUserToken)
```

**Strategy**

```
passport.use(new passportGoogle.OAuth2Strategy(googleConfig, async (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        // Check for existing user
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({
            providers: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    provider: 'Google',
                    providerId: profile.id
                }
            }
        })

        // If user exists return done
        if (existingUser) return done(null, existingUser)

        // If user does not exist create a new user
        const newUser = await new User({
            name: profile.displayName,
            providers: [
                {
                    provider: 'Google',
                    providerId: profile.id
                }
            ]
        }).save()

        // Create profile with new user information
        const newProfile = await new Profile({
            userId: newUser.id
        }).save()

        return done(null, newUser)
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked a bit at your code and haven't seen any serializing/deserializing going on. Usually you'd have to go through this process to be able to connect with whatever authentication strategy you are using.

Here is a snippet of code that you could use in the file you keep your strategies:

```
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    done(null, user);
  });
});
```

Maybe you could look it up in more detail in the documentation. Here is a link http://www.passportjs.org/docs/ go to the sessions part. Plus, make sure to look at how the app.use is put together with the .session() func.